# Card Img Overlay, Overflows Card Body

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a page with cards. There is a thumbnail at the top and an overlay.
The body of the card must be outside of the overlay but it overflows onto the body

Check demo

```
https://codepen.io/snarex/pen/NWKbgZM
```

This is a sample from my card design

```
    <div class="card shadow bg-white rounded">
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/360/any" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

    <div class="card-img-overlay text-center d-flex">
        <img src="http://wptf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/play-button.png"
             class="w-25 align-self-center mx-auto "
             alt="">
    </div>
</a>
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">
        <a href="#" class="text-info">*</a></h5>
</div>
```

I am looking forward to have something like this, but with play button as I have in codepen demo
[image]

Comment: @NIshamMahsin please check I added.

Comment: put the image into a div and set `overflow:hidden` and `position:relative` to wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add "position: relative" to the link element() so that the overlay connects to it instead of the higher parent

```
    <div class="card shadow bg-white rounded">
        <a href="#" class = "position-relative">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/360/any" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

    <div class="card-img-overlay text-center d-flex">
        <img src="http://wptf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/play-button.png"
             class="w-25 align-self-center mx-auto "
             alt="">
    </div>
</a>
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">
        <a href="#" class="text-info">Hızlı olan kazansın: SEO’nun gizli kahramanı “Page Speed”</a></h5>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but I just found this one it works without needing position relative https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/tutorial/bootstrap_4_cards_image_overlay I am trying to make it work as much as bootstrap way. Can you please check

Comment: You can use bootstraps "position-relative" class on it. In the other example there is no overlay, it is just the text that's aligned to the top